# How to write code inside ajax without xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code like this before:

```
<script>

function()
{

//*code*
fxajax.sendData
({
    url:"",
    data:{},
    success:function(){},
    error:function(){}

});
}

</script>
```

But my manager wants me to put my code inside the ajax so i put it inside beforeSend

```
<script>

function()
{

fxajax.sendData
({
    beforeSend: function()
                {/*code*/}
    url:"",
    data:{},
    success:function(){},
    error:function(){}

});
}

</script>
```

My problem is beforeSend is not executed but url, data, success and error works fine. Then I think maybe its because I don't have an XHR request.

Any idea how I should implement this code?

Comment: Does the xhr library that you are using support the beforeSend action?

Comment: How would I know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// set a 1 second to fire ajax request
 setTimeout(function () {
    // url of the image
    var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg';

    $.ajax({
      url : '', // url request
      type : "GET", // type of request,
      beforeSend : function () {
        var i = new Image();
          i.src = url;
          i.onload = function () {
            // change it to div
            $('div').append(i);
          }

          console.log("ajax is firing");
      },
      success: function () {

      },
      error : function (xhr, txtstatus, text) {
        console.log(txtstatus);
        console.log('error');
        // any error from request
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here is a simple [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/347882f3/)

Comment: I don't have any request. My code is just for attaching an image on a div. My manager wants it inside the ajax. 

I think mine don't work because I don't request anything. How can I implement this? I am not required to put it inside beforeSend but inside Ajax.

Comment: then where you want to put it,
you can try to put it on the beforeSend or complete

Comment: @EmpressT you can try to check again